# React context provider and consumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ThemeContext.js

```
import React from 'react';

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(null);

export default ThemeContext;
```

Parent component

```
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';

class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={'green'}>
        <D />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Component C is below component D.

```
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';

class C extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {coloredTheme =>
          <div style={{ color: coloredTheme }}>
            Hello World
          </div>
        }
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

What makes me vague is that we are importing "ThemeContext.js" from the provider(component A) and the consumer(component C). So how could the two components share a single ThemeContext instance( how does the consumer access the providers context without sharing a single one) , both have their own ThemeContext?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the relationship between `Provider` parent and `Consumer` descendants that allows to share values between them.

`<ThemeContext.Consumer>` in `C` has `<ThemeContext.Provider value={'green'}>` as parent, so it's able to access `green` context value as `coloredTheme` callback parameter.

> both have their own ThemeContext?

ES modules are evaluated once and result in singletons. `ThemeContext` is context object. It is same in `A` and `C` modules.

Comment: Thank you @estus, you helped me a lot.

Comment: React Context API seems to be similar to Lightweight PicoContainer Dependency Injection in Java world

Comment: "`<ThemeContext.Consumer>` in `C` has `<ThemeContext.Provider value={'green'}>` as parent..." We don't see `C`'s parent in this example. The `ThemeContext.Provider` does not appear to be a parent of `C`.

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica The whole hierarchy is shown in the question, "Component C is below component D"

Comment: I don't see the definition of `D` anywhere, nor can I tell what the parent of `C` is. I read the question again and don't see anything there. How can you tell that `C` is a child of `D`?

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica This is presumed by the phrase, "Component C is below component D", I'm quite sure it's supposed to mean that C is a child of D. This is confirmed by the fact that code is workable for the OP, otherwise it wouldn't due to how React context works, there should be a hierarchical relationship between a provider and consumer

Comment: Thank you! I read the post over and over and didn't see that! Yes, I agree! Merry Christmas!

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica Same to you! Glad this was helpful.