# Passing Props in Context [React]

Tags: reactjs

I have 5 generation structure of components:
A-B-C-D-E

Firsly i create a context:

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext();
```

in A is created provider

```
     <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.props.name} >
                    <Col><Menu navbarState={this.state.name} /></Col>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
```

And in E i need to create context with `{this.props.name}`

```
export class Panel extends RoleAwareComponentUser{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // component will be visible for the roles below:
        this.authorize = ['user'];  
      }

    render(){
    const jsx =(
    <div>
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
            {value => <Col><Link className={{value: value}} to= "/HomePage">Panel</Link></Col>}
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    </div>
      );

      return this.shouldBeVisible() ? jsx : null;

    }
}
```

The output of Link className is "[Object, object]"

How can i pass the props correctly?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, inheritance of components is not recommended by the React Dev team. Instead, you should use composition. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance

Comment: Hmm, So if I have the component in component in another component it's not recommended practice?

Comment: Having composition of components is fine. But in here, your component inherits RoleAwareComponentUser.

Comment: ok I understand, do You know a different method of folding / showing components depending on the role?

Comment: You should take a look at Higher Order Components.

Comment: Why are you using it like `className={{value: value}}`? `className` prop value is expected to be a string while an object was given.

Comment: so, what syntax is correct in this case?

Comment: @PiotrŻak What are you trying to achieve? What is `value` value and what is `className` expected to be equal to for `Link`?

Comment: className in jsx should be "ThemeContext.Provider value", precisely {this.props.name}

Comment: `className={value}`, I guess. Does this work as intended? Please, use `@` in comments, otherwise users won't be notified of your comments.

Comment: @estus
When I change it to {value}, className doesn't exist.

Comment: Then provider value wasn't passed, or `props.name` was falsy. This will happen if <ThemeContext.Consumer> doesn't have <ThemeContext.Provider> as a parent. This isn't clear from the code you've posted, i.e. how A and E are related. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate your problem.

Comment: @estus

Ok thank You, the value from Provider was falsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stringified object like `"[Object, object]"` means that object value were provided in a place where a string is expected.

It should be:

```
<ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {value => <Col><Link className={value} to= "/HomePage">Panel</Link></Col>}
</ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

`className` accepts strings, but `class` attribute won't be added if a value is falsy.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51970110/3731501), it is a hierarchy of `Provider` and `Consumer` components that allows to pass the context, so `<ThemeContext.Consumer>` should have `<ThemeContext.Provider>` as a parent.

If there is proper hierarchy but context `value` is falsy, this means that `this.props.name` was falsy when it was passed as provider `value` prop:

```
<ThemeContext.Provider value={this.props.name}>...
```